# No execution till bootstrap modal returns value

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm using [Bootsrap Modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) in my Project. I'm not able to post my code.

So I'm explanning my scenario with this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeysinghanbu/bwxnx4p7/1/).

I'm having two modals `modal1`,`modal2` and getting value from `modal1` and displaying to `modal2`.

Once I run below code. I'm getting both modal not one by one.

Is it possible to stop execution till `modal1` returns value.

```
  $('.btn').click(function() {
    $('#modal1').modal();
    var returnedvalue = $('#modalvalue').val();
    $('#Response').text(returnedvalue);
    $('#modal2').modal();
 });
```

**FULL CODE   [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeysinghanbu/bwxnx4p7/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to solve this problem is to perform the rest of your function within an event listener on the first modal. Modifying your function, I came up with this:

```
$('#opener').click(function() {
  $('#modal1').modal();
  $('#modal1').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    var returnedvalue = $('#modalvalue').val();
    $('#Response').text(returnedvalue);
    $('#modal2').modal();
  });
});
```

I also changed your main button to have an ID so that your event listener wasn't listening to all clicks on elements with the .btn class.

```
<a id="opener" class='btn btn-primary' data-direction='top'>Modal</a>
```

You can see this working in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gerrit0/ur73n6ky/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Call the second modal when click on button inside first modal

**HTML**

```
<div id="modal1" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal 1</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p><input type="text" id="modalvalue"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" id="btn1" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->

<div id="modal2" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal 2</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <h3>
            Response from Modal1: <span id="Response"></span>
      </h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->




<a class='btn btn-primary btn' data-direction='top'>Modal</a>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$('.btn').click(function() {
    $('#modal1').modal();

});

$('#btn1').click(function() {
var returnedvalue = $('#modalvalue').val();
   $('#modal2').modal();
   $('#Response').html(returnedvalue);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a distinct class for each modal button, change the text in the second click event (when you click save for the first modal)

```
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary save">Save changes</button>
<a class='btn btn-primary btn main' data-direction='top'>Modal</a>
```

js:

```
$('.main').click(function() {
    $('#modal1').modal();


});
$('.save').click(function(){
  $('#modal1').modal('hide');//hide the first modal
  var returnedvalue = $('#modalvalue').val();
  $('#Response').text(returnedvalue);
  $('#modal2').modal();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0zw7r1r5/

Answer (score 0):

You must first use $('#modal1').modal(); to show in screen
after modal1 button click then show modal2

```
$('.btn').click(function() {
    $('#modal1').modal();

});

$('#modal1 .btn-primary').click(function(){

    $('#modal1').modal('hide');

   var returnedvalue = $('#modalvalue').val();
    $('#Response').text(returnedvalue);
    $('#modal2').modal();
})
```

Comment: did you read the annoying little error that made you put the link in quotes?

Comment: when i was trying to correct the post you comment :((;

Answer (score 0):

try to use call function into model.if call back function if working.then use below code :

```html
 $('.btn').click(function () {
        $('#modal1').modal('show', function (data) {
            var returnedvalue = data;
            if (data == 'yourvalue')
            {
                $('#modal2').modal('show');
                $('#Response').text(returnedvalue);
            }
           
            
        });
        
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The code that you want.

```js
$('.btn').click(function() {
    $('#modal1').modal();
    
});


function showModel2(){
 var returnedvalue = $('#modalvalue').val();
    $('#Response').text(returnedvalue);
    $('#modal2').modal();
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="modal1" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal 1</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <input type="text" id="modalvalue">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="showModel2()">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->

<div id="modal2" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal 2</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <h3>
            Response from Modal1: <span id="Response"></span>
      </h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->




<a class='btn btn-primary btn' data-direction='top'>Modal</a>
```